# Create file wrapper that can be opened

Tags: python, file, wrapper

I need to handle a ZIP file with specialized content and thus want to create a wrapper, so that I can use something like

```
with open(MySpecialFile('/path/to/file.zip', 'rb')) as msf:
    <snip>
```

I already know how to implement the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, but I cannot find any documentation of how I can make the object be openable.
I tried to implement an `__open__` function in the hope that python does apply the open() method in this way. Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     def __open__(self):
...         print('Opened!')
... 
>>> with open(Foo()) as f:
...     print('yay')
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invalid file: <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f93b630ab00>
```

What is the right way to create a custom object that can be opened using `open()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `__open__` method. Instead, you should create something which implements the [`file` API](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). A simple class will do as long as it implements all the necessary methods.

Then you can say:

```
with openMySpecialFile('/path/to/file.zip', 'rb') as msf:
    ...
```

where `openMySpecialFile()` is a factory function which builds in instance of the "something" above and returns it.

Comment: So I assume that there is no way to use the built-in open() on my wrapper instance directly?

Answer (score 3):

Or just wrap `open` :

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, fpath, mode):
        self.f = fpath
        self.mode = mode
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'context begun'
        self.file = open(self.f, self.mode)
        return self.file
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print 'closing:', exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb
        self.file.close()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.f
with Foo('file.spc', 'rb') as f:
    print f.read()

>>> 
context begun
filecontentsfilecontentsfilecontentsfilecontents


closing: None None None
>>>
```